# not able to POST required data in django templates

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to POST a form from my html to views.py in django, but I am not able do it.

This is my html. This form should post the url of the downloaded image to the views.py function.

```
      {% for x in photo %}
         <a class="down" href="{{x.image.url}}" onclick="myfunc()" download="none">get</a>
         <form action="/image_info/" method="POST" id='dform'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name='d_button' type="hidden" value="{{x.image.url}}">
         </form>
      {% endfor %}
```

This is my javascript function to submit form whenever the `get` link is pressed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfunc()
  {
    document.getElementById("dform").submit();
    console.log('hello');
  }
</script>
```

this is my views.py. This should take the image url from the form and display it in the new page.

```
def show_image():
    image_url = request.POST.get('d_button', None)
    return render(request, 'show_image.html', {'image': image_url)
```

but my problem is that the form is not returning the url of the image that is clicked instead it is returning the url of first link. for example

```
link1 
link2
link3
link4
```

if I click on link3, it is downloading the image in link3 but POSTING the url of link1.

This is a bit tricky to explain but this is the best I can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of photo in your template?

Comment: @Vincent photo is a queryset containing all the objects of model that is the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML ids are supposed to be **unique**. You are looping while generating these forms and hence generate a bunch of duplicate ids, so when you write `document.getElementById("dform")` the **first** matching element is selected.

One solution would be to use `forloop.counter` to generate unique ids and use them. We would set these ids as an attribute on the anchor and pass the anchor element to the onclick function:

```
{% for x in photo %}
    <a class="down" href="{{x.image.url}}" onclick="myfunc(this)" data-target="dform-{{ forloop.counter }}" download="none">get</a>
    <form action="/image_info/" method="POST" id='dform-{{ forloop.counter }}'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name='d_button' type="hidden" value="{{x.image.url}}">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Now in your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(elem)
    {
        document.getElementById(elem.getAttribute("data-target")).submit();
        console.log('hello');
    }
</script>
```